# ServletContext#getRequestDispatcher() adds an extra slash, resulting in "Requested URI does not match Resource path pattern" error on cloud servers

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc, requestdispatcher

The below spring controller forwards the request to a static JSP path using `RequestDispatcher.forward()`

```
RequestDispatcher rs = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/security/html/blah.jsp");                        
try {
    rs.forward(request, response);
} catch (Exception e) { 
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The code is working perfectly fine in local machines. But when I deploy it on cloud servers, I  get a stacktrace stating

> **javax.servlet.ServletException: Requested URI
>   [//security/html/blah.jsp] does not match Resource path pattern**

For some reason, a extra slash is added in the resource path, which is causing the issue. If I enter the URL (by removing the extra slash) manually in the address bar, it works.

Since it is a internal forward, I am not even sure whether an extra slash is added in the local machines or not, because the below URL (with two slashes in the path) works locally but not working on cloud servers

> **IP:port/context//security/html/blah.jsp**

I saw a similar issue on the below link (unfortunately, without a solution)

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?115666-Extra-leading-slash-added-by-RequestDispatcher-include()&p=382817#post382817

Comment: What does it do when you remove the leading `/` -  `request.getRequestDispatcher("security/html/blah.jsp");`?

Comment: Sorry, we are fetching the requestDispatcher from the servlet context not the request. I am modifying the question. If I remove the slash from the URL, I get a IllegalStateException

Comment: Leading slash is required. What type of servlet container are you using for development (where it works) and on what container it does not work?

Comment: Tomcat. If I dont give the leading slash in the request dispatcher occupied from servlet context, I get IllegalStateException

Comment: @Vivek Could you check which implementation of `RequestDispatcher` is used when running on local Tomcat and when deployed on remote machine? Just log `dispatcher.getClass().getCanonicalName()`

Comment: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher from Apache Tomcat 5.5

Comment: Could you provide some more information regarding your configuration, e.g. DispatcherServlet mappings?

Comment: Could this (unanswered) question be related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379973/double-forwarded-servletrequest-using-requestdispatcher-forward-malforms-url-a?rq=1

Comment: could you post web.xml ,firstpage and dispatcher xml?

Comment: @xwoker, yes it seems to be the same problem. But no answer for that question as well :(

Comment: @Vivek: Can you please check the `URL` of the page to which the original request was made? How does is look like?

Comment: As I mentioned, it looks like "/security/html/somepageName.html"

Comment: If I may ask Vivek, under which folder is the security folder ?

Comment: Similar behavior is noted at https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46131 where a Context element in a config file wrongly had "/" for the root context instead of the empty string "".  You might check if that's the case in the Tomcat configuration on your cloud servers.

Comment: I checked the mentioned configuration in my tomcat server. In my local server (where it seems to be working fine) has a context path of "/" which is same as the cloud server. The given link suggests to make context path empty "", I tried that, but still getting the same issue :(

Comment: hey Vivek, can you share your web.xml file?

Answer (score -1):

You can replace the leading / with getServletContext().getContextPath() to make it work in any environment. Please check and let me know if this solves your problem.